# Is there a way of getting multiple levels of hue in Seaborn or Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter, seaborn

I can get a table in the form I need,

[image: required table]
but the closest plot I can manage with 3 dimensions is:
[image: achieved graph]

When I'm trying to get something like this:
[image: required graph]

```py
group_fields = ['ABS', 'Schooling']
output_fields = ['Gain S/L per Term', 'Gain Read per term', 'Gain Write per term']

table_data = school[group_fields + output_fields]
table = table_data.groupby(group_fields).mean()
display(table)

long_school = pd.melt(school, id_vars=['ABS', 'Schooling'], var_name='Macro', 
                      value_vars=outputFields, value_name='Increase')

sns.catplot(data=long_school, kind='bar', col='Schooling', x='ABS', hue='Macro', ci=False, y='Increase')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple levels of hue"?

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a list of colors for the color palette. For an example with seaborn, see [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html#using-named-colors-from-the-xkcd-color-survey).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out the style option? In Seaborn lineplot, you can colour by hue variable, and have line pattern by style variable.